# About limit of sequence and function at infinity

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Suppose that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n\lambda ) = 0 \quad \forall \lambda  \in (0,1).$$

Is it necessary that $$\lim_{x \to  +\infty} f(x) = 0?$$

I tried to construct an example to show it's not true, but I failed. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you know Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: For the continuous case see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/101086

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual question along these lines assumes that $f$ is continuous.  Then Arpit's hint is helpful.

But for this one...  Define
$f(x) = 1$ if $x=\pi^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$ and $0$ otherwise.  For each $\lambda$, the sequence $(f(n\lambda))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is zero except for at most one term, so converges to zero.  But $f(x)$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: Your example is nice. Thank you for helping me!