# Limit of a special function with integers

Tags: real-analysis

Let a continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that:$\forall \theta >0,n \in \mathbb N^+$,we have
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(n \theta)=0.$$
Prove that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$$

Comment: could you update the question with definition of both limits and try to derive one from the other and let's see where you get stuck?

Comment: HINT: Baire Category theorem

Comment: This question has been already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101086/lim-n-to-inftyfnx-0-implies-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0