# f(tn) converges -> f(t) converges

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

Claim:
Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function, for which $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(nt) = 0$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) holds for all $t \in [0, \infty)$. 
Then $\text{lim}_{t \rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0$.

I think you need to use Baire's category theorem, so i tried to somehow formulate the condition $\text{lim}_{t \rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0$ into something with subsets of $[0, \infty)$, and arrived at:

$\text{lim}_{t \rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0 \iff \forall \epsilon > 0: \ \{f < \epsilon\} \supset [R_{\epsilon},\infty) \text{ for one } R_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{R}$.

But i don't really have an idea how to proceed.

Comment: This has been answered long ago, in the early stages of MSE.

Comment: Just for slightly more context, if $f$ is not required to be continuous, then I think the following would be a counter-example:


$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\, x=\sqrt{2}+n,\ n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\\
      0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101086/lim-n-to-inftyfnx-0-implies-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne).