# If $\,\lim_{n\to\infty}f(nx)\,$ exists, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then so does $\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $\,f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. The following limit exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$: 
$$\lim_{n\to ∞} f(nx) ,$$

where $n \in \mathbb N$. Is it correct that:
$$\lim_{x\to ∞} f(x) ,$$ 
exists if:

a) $f$ any function,

b) $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't think this problem is anywhere near as trivial as the answers below seem to imply.

Comment: I agree... Please comment on my answer, I might be way off... but maybe not

Comment: I don't know whether this is even worth remarking, but uniform continuity is sufficient. Any attempt at an argument that I can think of starts to use uniform continuity...

Comment: I've changed it. It is traditional for $n$ to implicitly represent an integer.

Answer (score 17):

A counterexample has already been provided in response to (a). I'll answer (b) in the affirmative. The solution, which relies on the Baire Category Theorem, is an extension of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classic-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-connect) from a while back, which is similar but makes the helpful assumption that the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(nx)$ are all zero. There is, however, a completely different solution—given in *Selected Problems in Real Analysis* by Makarov et al.—that does not use the Baire Category Theorem, but instead relies on a lemma: If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are unbounded open sets in $\mathbb R^+$, then there is a number $x_0$ such that $nx_0\in G_i$ for infinitely many $n$. The proof employs [Cantor's intersection theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_intersection_theorem). Links to the book can be found in the other question I mentioned.

Anyways, here's my own proof. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and define
$$
E_N = \left\{x: |f(nx)-f(mx)|\leq \epsilon\text{ for all }n,m\geq N\right\}.
$$
The sets $E_N$ are closed (write $E_N$ as the intersection over $n,m\geq N$ of the sets $\{x:|f(nx)-f(mx)|\leq\epsilon\}$, which are closed by the continuity of $x\mapsto |f(nx)-f(mx)|$). But also $[0,\infty)\subset\bigcup_NE_N$, so the Baire Category Theorem furnishes a nonempty open interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R^+$ and an integer $N$ such that $(a,b)\subset E_N$. This means that if $x\in(na,nb)$ for some $n\geq N$, then $|f(x)-f(mx)|\leq\epsilon$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$.

Choose $M'\geq N$ so that
\begin{align*}
(M'a,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\geq M'}{(na,nb)};
\end{align*}
any $M$ bigger than $a/(b-a)$ will suffice. Thus, writing $M = M'a$,
\begin{align*}
\text{$|f(x)-f(mx)|\leq\epsilon\,$ for all $\,x>M$ and $m\in \mathbb N$.}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Next define $g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(nx)}$. We want to show that $g$ is constant. If $m$ is a positive integer, then $\{f(nmx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of $\{f(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and since the latter sequence converges to $g(x)$, the former does as well. Thus $g(x)=g(mx)$ for all integers $m\in \mathbb N$ and $x>0$. It follows by replacing $x$ with $x/m$ that $g(x/m) = g(x)$ and then that $g(x) = g(rx)$ whenever $r$ is rational. Therefore, as we'll see, it is sufficient to prove that $g(x) = g(y)$ when $x$ and $y$ are very large and very close to one another.

Making $m\to\infty$ in $(1)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\text{$|f(x)-g(x)|\leq\epsilon\,$ for all $\,x>M$.}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now pick $x,y>0$ arbitrarily. Then for all rational numbers $r$ and $s$ for which $rx$ and $sy$ are bigger than $Ma$, it follows from $(2)$ and the triangle inequality that
\begin{align*}
|g(x) - g(y)| & = |g(rx) - g(sy)| \\
& = |g(rx) - f(rx) + f(rx) - f(sy) + f(sy) - g(sy)| \\
&\leq 2\epsilon + |f(rx)-f(sy)|.
\end{align*}
Fixing $s$ and making $r\to sy/x$ through $\mathbb Q$, for instance, shows then that $|g(x) - g(y)|\leq 2\epsilon$; of course, $\epsilon$, $x$, and $y$ are arbitrary and so $g$ is constant, say $g\equiv A$.

Finally, $(2)$ shows that $f(x)\to A$ as $x\to\infty$, hence the limit exists.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and delete my post, which was little more than an unsuccessful attempt at bumping this question. I'll probably assign the bounty to you, but I'm going to wait to see if anyone has anything else to add.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** If $f(x)=1$ on rationals and $0$ otherwise, then for any $x\in\Bbb R$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(nx)$ exists. What about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?

What changes if $f(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: It seems there are a few people who understand how to turn your answer into a solution. Alas, I am not among them.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: I think the assumption that is not stated in the question is that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If so, then $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $nx\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Similarly, $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $nx\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I know. My comment above, as well as my bounty, is for a solution to b).

Comment: This problem is mentioned [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129666/classic-applications-of-baire-category-theorem) and [these notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/baire-category.pdf) are given as a reference. As @Nick Strehlke's answer would suggest, the case where $f$ is continuous is an application of the Baire Category theorm.

Comment: @Mike The problem you reference is similar, but this problem does not assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(nx) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(ny)$ for $x \not = y$, which does make things a little trickier—at least, it tripped me up for a bit.

Comment: @NickStrehlke: Fair point. I gave your answer +1 by the way. Clayton, sorry for putting these comments on your answer, I meant to put them under the question. But I guess they are here now, oops.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! And I second your apology for the clutter.

Answer (score 7):

We shall need the following fact:

**Fact.** *Let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]\subset(0,\infty)$ be a sequence of nontrivial closed intervals with $\,a_n\to\infty$,
and $K$ an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$, and let $S_K$ be the set
$$
S_K=\Big\{x\in(0,\infty) : \text{$nx\in \bigcup_{k\in K} I_k$ 
for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$}\Big\}.
$$
Then $S_K$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$.
Further, if $K, L\subset \mathbb N$, with $|K|=|L|=\aleph_0$, then $S_K\cap S_L$ is also dense in $(0,\infty)$.*

We postpone the proof of this fact. Clearly, for every $\,x_0\in(0,\infty)$
$$
\liminf_{x\to\infty}\, f(x) \le
\lim_{n\to\infty}\,f(nx_0)\le
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\, f(x).
$$
Hence, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\,f(x)$ does NOT exist, then we can pick
$\,A,B \in\mathbb R$, such that
$$
\liminf_{x\to\infty}\, f(x) < A < B < \limsup_{x\to\infty}\, f(x).
$$
There exist sequences $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\},$ with $x_n\to\infty, y_n\to \infty$, $f(x_n)\to \liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and
$f(y_n)\to \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. These sequence can be chosen so that
$$
f(x_n)<A<B<f(y_n), \quad n\in\mathbb N.
$$

Due to the continuity of $f$ it is possible to define nontrivial closed intervals $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$, such that
$\,x_n\in(a_{2n-1},b_{2n-1}),\,y_n\in(a_{2n},b_{2n}),$ and
$$
f\,\big|_{I_{2n-1}} <A\quad\text{while}\quad f\,\big|_{I_{2n}} >B,
\quad \text{for all $\,n\in\mathbb N$}.
$$

Due the ***Fact***, there exists a dense set of points $x$, with the property
that, for infinitely many $n$'s the multiple $nx$ belongs to $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N} I_{2k-1}$, and for infinitely many $n$'s the multiple $nx$ belongs to $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N} I_{2k}$.

This in turn implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(nx)$ does not exist, for every such point.

*Proof of the Fact.* Let $[c,d]\subset(0,\infty)$. We shall prove that
there exists an $x\in [c,d]$, such that for infinitely many $n$ the multiple
$nx$ belongs to an interval of the form $I_k$, $\,k\in K$, and for
infinitely many $n$ the multiple $nx$ belongs to an interval of the form
$I_\ell$, $\ell\in L$.

Observation. *If $\,a_m > \big(\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{d}\big)^{-1},$
and $\,N=\left\lfloor\frac{a_m}{d} \right\rfloor+1,\,$ then $[c',d'] = \frac{1}{N}[a_m,b_m]\cap [c,d]$
is a nontrivial interval.*

To establish this observation, it suffices to show that
$\displaystyle\frac{a_m}{N}=\frac{a_m}{\lfloor\frac{a_m}{d}\rfloor+1}\in (c,d)$. Clearly,
$$
a_m > \frac{1}{\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{d}} 
\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, \frac{1}{c}>\frac{1}{a_m}+\frac{1}{d}
\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_m}+\frac{1}{d}}>c
$$
and hence
$$
c<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{a_m}}=
\frac{a_m}{\frac{a_m}{d}+1} \le 
\frac{a_m}{\lfloor\frac{a_m}{d}\rfloor+1} < \frac{a_m}{\frac{a_m}{d}}=d,
$$
and therefore, $\displaystyle
[c_1,d_1] = \frac{1}{N}[a_m,b_m]\cap [c,d]$
is a nontrivial interval.

This observation allows us to recursively define a sequence of nontrivial
closed intervals $J_n=[c_n,d_n]$, where $[c_0,d_0]=[c,d]$, $[c_1,d_1]=[c',d']$, and we pick
the $a_m$'s, so that the first one is in $K$, the next in $L$, the next in $K$ and so on. In
this way we have a sequence of closed intervals

This is based on the observation that, if $a_n$ is
sufficiently large, then
$$
[c',d']=\frac{1}{N}[a_n,b_n]\cap[c,d]\quad\text{is a nontrivial interval},
$$
for $N=\lfloor a_n/d\rfloor+1$. This allows us to recursively define a sequence of nontrivial
closed intervals $J_n=[c_n,d_n]$, where $[c_0,d_0]=[c,d]$, $[c_1,d_1]=[c',d']$, and we pick
the $a_n$'s, so that the first one is in $K$, the next in $L$, the next in $K$ and so on. In
this way we have a sequence of closed intervals
$$
J_0\supset J_1\supset\cdots\supset J_n\supset J_{n+1}\supset\cdots.
$$
Clearly $S=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} J_n\ne\varnothing$, and for each $x\in S$, infinitely
many multiples belong to $I_k$'s, $k\in K$, while infinitely
many multiples belong to $I_\ell$'s, $\ell\in L$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have made some changes in my post. I hope that now my argument is clearer.

Comment: (+1) Utmost clear, thank you very much! Amazing: it does *not* use Baire's category theorem. Is it close to  the one in *Selected Problems in Real Analysis* by Makarov et al., alluded to by Nick Strehlke in his answer?

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know, but I am intrigued now to take a look at Makarov's book.

Answer (score 0):

If for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the limit, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(nx)$$ exists.  Then in particular, it exists for $x=1$.  It is NOT necessarily the case that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$ 
exists, where we just change symbols in the limit.

Consider the comments comments below.

Comment: So continuity is not necessary as Matt Rigby seems to suggest.....  I think.

Comment: No... "$n$" is most likely intended to be an integer.

Comment: Does it REALLY matter?  I mean is not the limit as some integer tends to infinity the same as the limit of any real number.  To make my point more clear.  Given the function, $f(n)=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$; we have the following, $f(2n) = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, however the limit does not exist, because the limit can't differentiate between "even" and "odd" infinity (there's only one limit... if it exists).

Comment: Let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is an integer and $0$ otherwise. The limit as the integer $n$ tends to $\infty$ exists; as the real variable $x$ tends to $\infty$, the limit doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave my post because I think its a natural mistake and people should see why its wrong.  I'll edit it, to reflect the error.