# $\forall x>0:f(nx)\mathrm{ converges}$, so does $f$ at infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\forall x>0$ the sequence $\{f(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges. Does $f$ have limit at infinity?

I tried first to show that $f$ is at least bounded and it sufficies to show that $\left\{\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f(n\cdot 1/t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\right\}_{t=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, but I got nothing from this... Can you give any hint?

Comment: This is a very popular application of Baire Category Theorem and it has been answered long back.

Comment: @geetha290krm Is this comment helpful? You should mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A classical problem about limit of continuous function at infinity and its connection with Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\,\lim_{n\to\infty}f(nx)\,$ exists, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then so does $\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616745/if-lim-n-to-inftyfnx-exists-for-all-x-in-mathbb-r-then-so-does)