# $\{f(nh)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, does $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

While I'm looking at this assertion:

> Suppose $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\forall h>0$，$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(nh)$ exists, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

I wonder what happens if we just assume nothing or $f$ is only continuous. Is there a counterexample?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616745/473276). It's quite a hard question!