# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(nx\right)=0\quad\forall x>0$ imply $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f\left(x\right)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Function $f$ is continuous on $\left[0,+\infty\right)$,
does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(nx\right)=0,\quad\forall x>0$

imply that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f\left(x\right)=0$?
If $f$ is not continuous, it is false. I don't know how to make use of the continuity.

Comment: @Mattos You shouldn’t have $n$ in the expression of $f(x)$. $n$ is an independent variable which is taken limit.

Comment: Let z = nx. The lim of f(z) with z tending to infinity is 0, where z is a real positive variable

Comment: @Aforest yes, the first limit refers to the limit of a sequence and the second limit is a limit of function.

Comment: More general question: Can "$\forall x > 0$" be replaced with "for _almost_ all $x>0$".

Comment: its hard to believe that this property doesnt hold for some discontinuous $f$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the property holds for continuous functions (see also [A classical problem about limit of continuous function at infinity and its connection with Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne))

For $\epsilon>0$, let $A_N=\bigcap_{n\geq N}\{x>0: f(nx)\leq \epsilon\}$. Then $A_N$ is closed by the continuity of $f$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(nx\right)=0$ implies that
$$\bigcup_{N\geq 0} A_N=(0,+\infty).$$
Hence, by  the [Baire Category Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), there exists some $N_0$ such that $A_{N_0}$ contains an open interval  $(a,b)$ which means that for $n≥N_0$ and $t\in (na,nb)$ we have that $f(t)\leq \epsilon$.
Finally note that for $n>a/(b-a)$, then  $nb>(n+1)a$ and therefore
$$t\in\bigcup_{n>\max(a/(b-a),N_0)}(na,nb)=(\delta,+\infty)\implies 0\leq f(t)\leq \epsilon$$
That is $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f\left(x\right)=0$.

P.S. For a proof without Baire Category Theorem see [Gowers's Weblog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/what-is-deep-mathematics/)

Comment: The formulation of Baire Category Theorem that you're using is: If a non-empty complete metric space is the countable union of closed sets, then at least one of these sets must have non-empty interior, but here $(0, +\infty)$ is not complete since $(\frac{1}{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence but converges to $0$ which does not belong to $(0, +\infty).$ So what am I missing here?

Comment: @Aryaman Jal Every locally compact Hausdorff space, like $(0,+\infty)$ is a Baire space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification