# Convergence of $a_n$ given $a_{\lfloor{x^n}\rfloor}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Sequence $a_n$ has a property that for every real $x > 1$, sequence $a_{\lfloor{x^n}\rfloor}$ converges to $0$. Does that mean that $a_n$ converges to $0$? I have tried to find a counterexample, but failed at it, so I think it might be true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: $a_n$ converges to 0 is equivalent to the following proposition : 

For every sequence $u_n$, there exists a real $x > 1$ such that $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cap \{\lfloor{x^n}\rfloor\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is infinite. I'm not sure how to procede from here.

Comment: For every *strictly increasing sequence $u_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will invoke the following result:

> **Proposition. (Croft's Lemma)** Suppose $U_1, U_2, \cdots$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the interior $\mathring{U}_j$ is unbounded above (i.e., $\sup \mathring{U}_j = \infty$) for each $j \geq 1$. Then the set
> $$ \mathcal{D} = \{ r \in \mathbb{R} : \text{for each $j \geq 1$, $n r \in U_j$ holds for infinitely many $n$} \} $$
> is dense in $(0, \infty)$.

We first check that this result gives an affirmative answer to OP's question:

> **Claim.** If $a_{\lfloor x^n \rfloor} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x > 1$, then $a_n \to 0$.

*Proof of Claim.* Define $f(r) = a_{\lfloor \exp(r) \rfloor}$. Then the assumption tells that $f(nr) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ along $\mathbb{N}$, for each $r > 0$. Assume otherwise that $a_n \not\to 0$. Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|a_n| > \epsilon$ holds for infinitely many $n$. Then

$$ U := \{ r : |f(r)| > \epsilon \} = \bigcup_{n \ : \ |a_n| > \epsilon} [\log n, \log(n+1)) $$

is such that its interior $\mathring{U}$ is not bounded from above. Then by the proposition, the set

$$ \mathcal{D} = \{ r \in (0, \infty) : \text{$nr \in U$ for infinitely many $n$} \} $$

is dense in $(0, \infty)$, and in particular, non-empty. But if $r \in \mathcal{D}$, then $|f(nr)| > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$, and so, $f(nr) \not\to 0$, a contradiction. $\square$

---

> **Lemma.** If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup U = \infty$, then $\bigcup_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n} U$ is dense in $(0, \infty)$.

*Proof.* Write $\mathcal{W}_N = \bigcup_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n} U$. We aim to show that $(a, b) \cap \mathcal{W}_N$ is non-empty for each $0 < a < b$. Since $(n+1) a < n b$ for sufficiently large $n$, we can find $r > 0$ such that

$$(r, \infty) \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq N}(n a, n b).$$

Since $U$ is not bounded above, $U \cap (r, \infty)$ is non-empty, so we can pick $x \in U \cap (r, \infty)$. Then $x \in (n a, n b)$ for some $n\geq N$, and hence $\frac{x}{n} \in (a, b) \cap \frac{1}{n} U$. $\square$

*Proof of Proposition.* Notice that
$$ \mathcal{D} = \bigcap_{j\geq 1} \bigcap_{N\geq 1}\bigcup_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n} U_j. $$
By the lemma, $\mathcal{D}$ is a countable intersection of open dense subsets of $(0, \infty)$. Then the conclusion follows from the [*Baire category theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) and the lemma above. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer because I will assume that 
$$
\tag{C}\forall x\gt 1, \quad \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_{\lfloor x^n\rfloor +1}=0.
$$
I do not not whether this is a consequence of the original assumption on $(a_n)_n$.

Define a continuous function on $[1,+\infty)$ in the following way. For each integer $n\geqslant 1$, we define $f(n):=a_n$ and we interpolate $f$ linearly on $(n,n+1)$. In particular, for $x\in [n,n+1]]$, $f(x)$ belongs to the interval 
$[\min\{a_n,a_{n+1}\},\max\{a_n,a_{n+1}\}\}]$.  It thus suffices to prove that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$.

Using (C) and the construction of $f$, we know that for all $x\gt 1$, the sequence $\left(f\left(x^n\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. Define $g(x):=f\left(e^x\right)$ for $x\geqslant 0$. [Since $g(nx)\to 0$ for all positive $x$, it follows that $g(x)\to 0$ as $x$ goes to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne) hence so does $f$.