# Limit of continuous function at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, functions, continuity

Consider a real, continuous function $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$.

1.
If for any $x > 0$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n\cdot x) = 0$, does it mean that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$ ?

2.
If for any $x > 0$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n + x) = 0$, does it mean that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$ ?

($n$ represents natural number)

Comment: As far as I understand that you mean once the sequence limit and once the limit of functions with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition, $(2.)$ is not true, but it will take some time until I've written a counterexample. And I'm optimistic that this counterexample will also work for the first case, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @brulemart arguing by contradiction do not give any insight to me (Warning: Careful usage of quantifiers is required). Can you give more details about your proposal?

Comment: Please clarify the "any $x$" part, do you mean some $x$ or all $x$? Note that if $x=\pi$ and $f(t)=\sin(t)$ then  $f(n\cdot x) = \sin(n\cdot\pi) = 0$ for all integer $n$, but $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ does not exist (values oscillate between $-1$ and $1$). Similarly, if $f(t)=\sin(\pi t)$ and $x=1$ then $f(n + x) =\sin(\pi(n + 1)) = 0$ for all integer $n$, but $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ does not exist.

Comment: "for any x" in this context means "for all x's" of course

Comment: @DIEGOR. you're right, I misunderstood the question. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

For **(1)**, surprisingly the answer is **affirmative**:

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $(0, \infty)$, and assume that
> $$ \lim_{\mathbb{N}\ni n\to\infty} f(nx) = 0 $$
> for all $x > 0$. Then
> $$ \lim_{\mathbb{R}\ni x\to\infty} f(x) = 0. $$

(In fact, the continuity assumption on $f$ can be relaxed so as to encompass piecewise continuous functions.) The proof hinges on an application of Baire's category theorem called *Croft's lemma*:

> **Croft's Lemma.** Let $U_1, U_2, \ldots$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the interior $\mathring{U}_j$ is unbounded above for each $j \geq 1$. Then the set
> $$ \mathcal{D} = \{ r \in \mathbb{R} : \text{for each $j \geq 1$, $n r \in U_j$ holds for infinitely many $n$} \} $$
> is dense in $(0, \infty)$.

Its proof can be found in other posting in MSE. For instance, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3016547/9340). Now let us see how this lemma helps prove the theorem:

> *Proof of Theorem.* For the sake of proof by contradiction, assume that $f(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
> $$U = \{ x \in (0, \infty) : |f(x)| > \varepsilon\}$$
> is not bounded above. Then by setting $U_j = U$ for all $j$ in Croft's lemma, we find that the set
> $$ \mathcal{D} = \{ x \in (0, \infty) : nx \in U \text{ infinitely often} \} $$
> is dense in $(0, \infty)$. In particular, $\mathcal{D} \neq \varnothing$. However, for each $x \in \mathcal{D}$, the sequence $(f(nx))_{n\geq 1}$ cannot converge to $0$, contradicting the assumption on $f$. Therefore the desired claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

With the test function (i.e. element of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$)
$$\phi_b(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(b^2/(x^2-b^2),\qquad&x\in]-b,b[\\
0,\qquad&x\notin]-b,b[
\end{cases}$$ for $b>0$ we define for $k\in\Bbb N$
$$\psi_k(x):=\phi_{1/k^2}(x-(k-1/k)),
$$
which is a function with a bump of height $e^{-1}$, width $2/k^2$ and center in $k-1/k$ and zero elsewhere. Now consider the function
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\psi_k(x)
$$
*Regarding the second question:* Let $x_0>0$ fixed and WLOG $x_0\leq1$. As $x_0$ contributes a constant shift for $f(n+x_0)$, in the case $x_0\neq1$ once $1-1/k-1/k^2$ has passed $x_0$ the function will never be anything else than zero. In the case $x_0=1$, the bump will never be above $n+x_0$ for $n$ big enough. So $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n + x_0) = 0$ is satisfied (with the sequence limit) but obviously not $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$.

Comment: I think that the second (i.e. the first question) part is not correct since fractional parts of $n*x_0$ are dense in $[0,1]$ for any irrational $x_0$.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking to rational numbers all the time. I will remove the last part.

Comment: Well, now, for a change, the first problem seems to be under question. I mean, I do not see how the function $f$ satisfies the condition. We should have $\lim f(n\cdot x) = 0$ as $n->\infty$ for any x.

Comment: The proof starts with 'Let $x_0>0$ fixed' which means arbitrary $x_0$ and then shows $f(n+x_0)\to0$ for $n\to\infty$. So it is proofed for ervery $x_0$. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I was talking about the first question (1). Somehow, you changed the order in which you answer these questions. In words, I do not see how the top part of your answer handles the first question. Why $f(n\cdot x)$ tends to $0$ for any $x$ ?

Comment: As in the comment above: you were right about my second part (regarding question 1.), that it was not correct. That's why I removed it and there is no more answer to question 1. left from me. The remaining answer is only for question 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122420/discussion-between-mag-and-salcio).

Answer (score 0):

*I will give contra-example for hypothesis 2.*

For any closed interval $I=[a,b]$ define *"impulse" function* $h(\cdot; I)$ to be any continuous function that is zero outside the interval $I$ and that has maximum $1$ on the interval $I$, e.g.
$$
  h(x;I) = \max\left\{
1 - \frac{2}{b-a}\left|x-\tfrac 1 2 (a+b)\right| ,0
\right\}.
$$

**Contra-example to claim 2:** Consider the sequence of intervals
$$
  I_n = [n+2^{-n},n + 2^{1-n}]
$$
and the function
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty h(x; I_n).
$$
This function is not convergent as $f(a_n)=1$ for the sequence of the midpoints
$$
  a_n = n + 3 \cdot 2^{-n+1}
$$
of the intervals $I_n$, but for any $x>0$ there is at most one $n$ such that $x+n \in I_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$.

**Edit:** As noted by @SangchulLee the following contra-example fails.

**Contra-example to claim 1:** The construction of this contra-example is analogous, we take into account the fact that $\log(n \cdot x) = \log(n) + \log(x)$. Consider the sequence of intervals
$$
  J_n = [\log(n)+2^{-n+1},\log(n) + 2^{-n}]
$$
and the function
$$
  g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty h(x; J_n).
$$
Note that $$\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \log(1+1/n) > 2/n > 2^{-n},$$
so the intervals $J_n$ are disjoint. It can also be seen that for any $x>0$ there is at most one $n$ such that $\log(x)+\log(n) \in J_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: In fact, the answer to Claim 1 is YES. To refute your alleged counter-example, let me briefly explain why it can fail. (To show that this construction actually fails, we need a deep result in analysis. So, let me only illustrate where it may go wrong.) In Case 2, both $\bigcup_n I_n$ and the sequence $(x+n)_{n\geq1}$ are "1-periodic" in a loose sense, hence it is possible to make them "out of sync". In Case 1, however, both $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} J_n$ and $(x+\log n)_{n\geq 1}$ has smaller gaps as $n$ increases, which opens up the possibility of infinitely many overlaps for cleverly chosen $x$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks a lot for your observation. I'm really impressed by the proof you provided!