# Let $f$ be a function that is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$and for any $x \in [0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem：
Let $f$ be a function that is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, and for any $x \in [0,+\infty)$, it satisfies
$
\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} f(x+n)=0, \quad n \text { is a positive integer. }
$

Prove that $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)=0$.

My solution：
First, by uniform continuity, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x', x'' \in [0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\left|x'-x''\right| < \delta$, we have
$
\left|f\left(x'\right)-f\left(x''\right)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \text{.}
$

For the above $\delta > 0$, let
$
M=\left[\frac{2}{\delta}\right]+1, \text{ and } x_i=\frac{i}{M}, i=0,1, \cdots, M,
$

then
$
[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^M\left(x_i-\delta, x_i+\delta\right) \text{.}
$

On the other hand, from the given condition, for the above $\epsilon$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for $n > N$, we have
$
\left|f\left(x_i+n\right)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}, \quad \forall i=0,1, \cdots, M \text{.}
$

Therefore, when $x > N+1$, we can decompose $x=[x]+\{x\}$, where the integer part $[x] \geq N+1$ and the fractional part $\{x\} \in [0,1)$. Thus, there must exist $i \in \{0,1, \cdots, M\}$ such that
$
\{x\} \in \left(x_i-\delta, x_i+\delta\right) \cap [0,1] \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left|x-[x]-x_i\right| < \delta \text{.}
$

Hence,
$
|f(x)| \leq \left|f(x)-f\left(x_i+[x]\right)\right| + \left|f\left(x_i+[x]\right)\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon \text{.}
$

This implies that
$
\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = 0
$.

And I found a similar problem:[A classical problem about limit of continuous function at infinity and its connection with Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63870/a-classical-problem-about-limit-of-continuous-function-at-infinity-and-its-conne)

I would like to know if the problem I just solved is related to the Baire category theorem. If we weaken the condition of uniform continuity to continuity, does the proposition still hold, or are there counterexamples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a counterexample.

For $n \in \mathbb N$, define $\phi_n:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$\phi_n(x) =  n x$ for $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$, $\phi_n(x) =-nx  +2$, for $ \frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{2}{n}$ and $\phi_n(x) =0$ otherwise.

Define $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(x-n)$.

Then
$
\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} f(x+n)=0.
$

But $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)$ does not converge.

Note that $f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally agree with you.